# What is this mint-family plant with small, pink flowers in Lynchburg, VA?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

The honey bees like this one. 
[image: plant and bee]

Each branch has many small flowers that bloom consecutively.
[image: flower]

Comment: Is it an annual, with a distinctive odor?

Comment: @J.Musser I'm not sure if its an annual, but it does have a mint-like odor when crushed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like one of the naturalized strains of [*Perilla frutescens*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perilla).

> Perilla frutescens has been widely naturalized in parts of the United States and Canada, from Texas and Florida north to Connecticut and into Ontario, and west to Nebraska. It can be weedy or invasive in some of these regions.

It certainly is a weed here, and although it is edible, I find the flavor repulsive. It tolerates poor and dry soil, and I see it more in the open woods than in my veggie garden.

See Comparison pics:

[image]

[image]

[image]